# Why isn't an image getting pasted on HTML? I've tried multiple ways but none of them work

Tags: html, image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0QNg.png)
My code (in notepad):

<img src="file:///C:/Users/dell/Downloads/Yashita/Restaurant%20Website/italian-food-Melbourne-museum.jpg" width="1024 height="977">

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gevlJ.png)
My code (in notepad):

<img src="italian-food-Melbourne-museum.jpg" width="1024 height="977">

I tried many websites like - w3schools.com, repl.it, notepad++ and so on. But however, the code doesn't work.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Try to share [code as text not as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) and use code blocks or code fences for formating

Answer (score 0):

Either pass
`"C:/Users/dell/Downloads/Yashita/Restaurant%20Website/italian-food-Melbourne-museum.jpg"` (absolute path)
or pass `"Yashita/Restaurant Website/italian-food-Melbourne-museum.jpg"`
(relative path).

Also, make sure you save your file with `.html` extension and not with `.txt` extension.